# How to get appVersion on current device using Parse API in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

What is the simplest way to retrieve the `appVersion` in the `Installation` class for the current user in Android using [Parse](https://www.parse.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets the `appVersion` currently installed on the device using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/).

`ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("appVersion")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. I used it in my apps:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

Best way to retrieve app Version Number and app Version Name.

Comment: This is correct, but your solution doesn't use the [Parse API](https://www.parse.com).